# ROW_NUMBER in cross apply generating "incorrect" values based on exists clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here is the sql:

```
-- Schema
DECLARE @ModelItem TABLE (
    ModelItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    MetamodelItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
DECLARE @MetamodelItemAncestor TABLE (
    MetamodelItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    ParentMetamodelItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    AncestorLevel INT
)
DECLARE @SolutionMetamodelItem TABLE (
    MetamodelItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    SolutionId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

INSERT INTO @ModelItem VALUES ('EC6AC6A9-684E-E611-8117-00155D026308', '2AB1F075-684E-E611-8117-00155D026308')
INSERT INTO @MetamodelItemAncestor 
VALUES ('2AB1F075-684E-E611-8117-00155D026308', '2AB1F075-684E-E611-8117-00155D026308', 0), 
('2AB1F075-684E-E611-8117-00155D026308', 'AA12E380-CA4D-E611-8117-00155D026308', 1)
INSERT INTO @SolutionMetamodelItem
VALUES ('2AB1F075-684E-E611-8117-00155D026308', 'f612a333-ca4d-e611-8117-00155d026308'),
('AA12E380-CA4D-E611-8117-00155D026308', 'fc160f3e-ca4d-e611-8117-00155d026308')

-- query
DECLARE @ModelItemId TABLE (EntityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
DECLARE @SolutionId TABLE (EntityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO @ModelItemId
VALUES ('EC6AC6A9-684E-E611-8117-00155D026308')

INSERT INTO @SolutionId
VALUES ('f612a333-ca4d-e611-8117-00155d026308'), ('fc160f3e-ca4d-e611-8117-00155d026308')

SELECT mia.*
FROM (
    SELECT M.EntityId AS ModelItemId, S.EntityId AS SolutionId
    FROM @ModelItemId AS M
    CROSS JOIN @SolutionId AS S
) AS m
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        MI.ModelItemId,
        OTA.ParentMetamodelItemId AS [MetamodelItemId],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MI].[ModelItemId] ORDER BY [OTA].[AncestorLevel] ASC) AS [AspectRank]
    FROM @ModelItem AS MI
    INNER JOIN @MetamodelItemAncestor AS OTA
        ON MI.MetamodelItemId = OTA.MetamodelItemId
    WHERE 
        MI.ModelItemId = m.ModelItemId
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @SolutionMetamodelItem AS MSMI
            WHERE MSMI.MetamodelItemId = OTA.ParentMetamodelItemId
                AND MSMI.SolutionId = m.SolutionId
        )
) mia

SELECT mia.*
FROM @ModelItemId AS m
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        MI.ModelItemId,
        OTA.ParentMetamodelItemId AS [MetamodelItemId],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MI].[ModelItemId] ORDER BY [OTA].[AncestorLevel] ASC) AS [AspectRank]
    FROM @ModelItem as MI
    INNER JOIN @MetamodelItemAncestor AS OTA
        ON MI.MetamodelItemId = OTA.MetamodelItemId
    WHERE 
        MI.ModelItemId = m.EntityId
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @SolutionMetamodelItem MSMI
            WHERE MSMI.MetamodelItemId = OTA.ParentMetamodelItemId
                AND MSMI.SolutionId IN (SELECT s.EntityId FROM @SolutionId AS s)
        )
) mia
```

Notice the AspectRank. In the second query it has correctly increased the value sequentially based on the partition.

Looking at the execution plan, for the first query it seems like the row_number (sequence project) is running concurrently to the scan of the `@solution` table, but I still am not fully sure why it has not increased the row number value since there a duplicate items.

Could someone explain this? I need to use the first approach because the cross apply query is in fact a UDF with the `ModelItemId` and `SolutionId` as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the cross apply is executed separately for each of the rows in your outer query -> each of the rows returned is the 1st (and only) row.

Why do you need to have the row number inside the cross apply, instead of being in the outer query, if that's actually where your data is?

Comment: Because in the end I needed a `AspectRank = 1` in the `WHERE` clause, along with my data.

Comment: Also, the row number (everything inside the `APPLY`) is inside a UDF.

Comment: So just add the row_number() in the outer query and wrap that inside a derived table to add the AspectRank = 1 clause? Still don't understand why you would even want the have the row_number inside the UDF since it can't know what the data is for the other rows.

Comment: Essentially this function is being called from entity framework. So I am performing a cross apply via linq. Now, I can only pass in the ModelItemId and SolutionId (i.e. uniqueidentifiers) via entity framework. I can only structure it using the first approach (as far as I know). The thing is the data is available in both approaches is it not? The only difference is the exsits clause, one is using an `IN`, the other is using `=` with the data on the outside of the apply (So this is the problem?)

Comment: What I can figure out, the problem is that your row_number is done in parts, which of course then resets it. I don't know anything about linq, but maybe someone can help if you're able to write a new question with a simple explanation of the problem

Comment: I actually did it another way by creating an indexed view and doing a cross apply with a `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY` sub-query. Seems ok for the moment! But thanks alot for your help and guidance.